# 3 users with the same handle having an argument?

Tags: discussion

Look at the answers to this question I asked:

[Can I get the return value of Shell.Application's ShellExecute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27222097/894506)

There are three different answers from three different users all with the same name and same avatar. I think it's the same guy but why would he do that? I'm not looking for any action here I'm just interested in if that's the same guy and why he would do that.

Comment: That question escalated quickly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All three are unregistered accounts so it's almost certain that all the answers are from the same user who, for some reason, has lost the cookies for his account or is posting from different devices.

In cases like this I, as a moderator, would like to be able to merge accounts, but all that would probably do (even if I could merge - which I can't) is end up with the user creating another unregistered account.

I'll leave a comment to encourage him to register one of the accounts and request the others get merged into that one.

Comment: And by the looks of it there is no cross voting...

Comment: don't you think it's weird though he's arguing with himself then. cause i'm not arguing with him. it just looks weird!

Comment: @test humans are weird.

Comment: @test I think he is arguing with you. You left a couple of comments on one of the answers and because he's on a different account/device he can't reply in the comments.

Comment: Maybe... each each answer looks PROGRESSIVELY HOSTILE WITH THE ALL CAPS. I already marked his answer as correct when there was only one answer. I'll chalk it up to inexperience.

Comment: @rene IINM, there is no voting with unregistered accounts, besides for accepting answers to their own questions.